# Laravel: Adding content to relationship's field with model

Tags: laravel, model

I have this kind of table in my database

```
User (id, name) 
UserHasTask (id, active, user_id, task_id, test)
Task (id, name)
```

So for one user, I can retrieve all tasks, active or not.
And when I edit a task it will be changed for every reference of this task attributed to users (I work with something like template of tasks).

And I would like to do the following:
When the `UserHasTask->test` is not null, I want to happen the value to the task's name.

So if I have:

```
User(10, 'John')
UserHasTask(20, 1, 10, 5, 'my_value')
Task(5, 'Task n°5')
```

The query `User::find(10)->getTaskByID(20)->task->name` should give me `Task n°5my_value`

---

I am currently using this function in my `UserHasTask`

```
public function name()
{
    $name = $this->task->name;
    if(isset($this->test))
        return $name . $this->test

    return $name;
}
```

But I'm forced to do this `User::find(10)->getTaskByID(20)->name()` instead of this `User::find(10)->getTaskByID(20)->task->name`

Comment: would you like to add your code as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Use hasManyThrough relation:

Refer laravel doc
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

you can specify the intermediate UserHasTask table

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

**In User Model**

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'UserHasTask');
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$user_tasks = User::find($user_id)->tasks; // all tasks assign to user

$task_name = array();
foreach($user_tasks as $user_task){
    $task_name[] = $user_task->name;
}
```